# EasyTracker (GoogleAnalytics) for Android in TabActivity and others

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use EasyTracker in my project. But one of the Activities extends TabActivity.

To use EasyTracker all activities have to extend TrackedActivity.

I guess it's not possible to extend it with my TabActivity subclass without modifying Android's or EasyTracker's source.

I'm wondering if it's possible to mix "normal" Tracking (which I would use for this Activity) and the inheritance Tracking of EasyTracker. But seems to be at least not advisable. From EasyTracker doc:

- Note that all of your Activities must extend TrackedActivity (or an
- equivalent Activity, like TrackedListActivity instead of ListActivity) for
- this Class to properly track application usage and time.

So what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty much simple, but I was to lazy to find it yesterday.

- Download source of EasyTracker
- Copy TrackedActivity and rename it in something like TrackedTabActivity
- Make it extend TabActivity instead of Activity
- Include this file in the project
- Make the subclass of TabActivity extend TrackedTabActivity instead

Same principle for other activity subclasses like PreferenceActivity, etc.